# Firma electrónica con C# no se muestran los certificados cuando se publica la web en IIS

Tags: c#, iis, firma-digital

Estoy implementando la firma de documentos pdf en mi portal. Estoy utilizando para leer los certificados con c# este código:

```
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection foundCertificates = 
            certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            List<X509Certificate2> certificados2 = foundCertificates.OfType<X509Certificate2> 
           ().Where(x => x.Subject.Contains("SERIALNUMBER")).ToList();
```

Todo me esta funcionando bien desde Visual Studio 2019, pero en cuanto publico la web en el servidor IIS los certificados ya no los lee.

El servidor IIS donde hago las pruebas está instalado en mi pc y usa el certificado ssl que instala Visual Studio 2019. Cuando accedo a la web me aparase como web segura, entra por el puerto 443 https.

Supuestamente si en Visual Studio funciona cuando la ejecuto, cuando publico la web también debería funcionar.

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto, alguna idea?

Gracias por adelantado

César